# Base Class, with method that returns Derived Class. design flaw?

Tags: python, object-oriented-design, circular-dependency

I'm writing a Math equation solver in python (for fun).
The first design that came to my mind:

- `Expression`: base class for every item in an equation (maybe bad name).
- `BinaryExpression` extends `Expression`: two expressions with a sign.
- `Expression + Expression` should provide a `BinaryExpression`, I do this through overriding the `__add__` method of `Expression`.

this is sort of circular dependency, which me and python both hates.

```
class Expression(object):
    def __add__(self, other):
        return BinaryExpresison(self, OP.ADD, other)

class BinaryExpress(Expression):
    def __init__(self, op, other):
        pass # super and staff
```

How would you do it?

Comment: Python has no problems with your circular dependency here.

Comment: However, I don't quite see why `BinaryExpression` is to be a subclass. [Python's AST](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html) makes `Expression` a top-level statement (inherits from `ast.mod`) while `BinOp` is a subclass of `ast.expr`.

Comment: BinOp is an Expression, because BinOp + BinOp should be a BinOp.

Comment: The Python AST actually has 3 'expression' types; the `ast.mod` subclass (a top-level program can consist of just the one expression), the expression *statement* (a full program consists only of `ast.stmt` types), and the `AST.expr` subclasses, which are the components of an expression.

Answer (score -1):

> How would you do it?

I'm not familiar with Python, but that sort of construct to build a composite or decorator pattern is something I've done a few times (albeit in C# and C++). It makes for a very nice interface and very usable code.

As long as you consider the `BinaryExpression` and similar composite/decorators part of the core library/API that everyone will want/use, that design perfectly fine.